# How to write and get value from DropDownList with Static Value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-select, html.dropdownlistfor

I'm new in ASP.NET MVC 4, and I'd like to write a simple DropDownListFor(or DropDownList) which gives static value. 
Example : I'd like to provide choices between 1, 2, 3 and 4

and I want to get value from Select Choices
Example :

```
if i select 1 --> int value = 1, 
if i select 2 --> int value = 2
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example, this will create a `<Select>` tag with the name attribute of "value" and with the options 1, 2, 3, and 4.

```
@{
  int[] choices = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
}

@Html.DropDownList("value", new SelectList(choices.AsEnumerable()))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It's Work.

How to set value Example : if i select 1 --> int value = 1

I don't know about Condition in if -> if(...){int value = 1}

Help Me Please T^T